# Unbounded positive self-adjoint without $0$ in its spectrum: can we construct its inverse using functional calculus?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $P$ be a positive, self-adjoint (unbounded) operator in a Hilbert space $H$ with $0\notin \sigma(P)$. Consider its spectral decomposition
$$P = \int_{\sigma(P)} t dE(t).$$
Since $0 \notin \sigma(P)$, we can define (the functional calculus)
$$P^{-}= \int_{\sigma(P)} t^{-1}dE(t).$$
This is an unbounded operator with domain
$$\left\{\xi \in H: \int_{\sigma(P)} t^{-2}dE_{\xi, \xi}(t) < \infty\right\}.$$

Is there a relation between this operator and the inverse operator $P(T)\to H: P(\xi)\mapsto \xi$? Are they equal? For example, it is not even clear to me that they have the same domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\D{\mathscr D}$Yes, $P^-=P^{-1}$.

Indeed, the resolvent set of $P$ is open and $0$ is in this set. So, $\si(P)$ is bounded away from $0$, and hence the domain $\D(P^-)$ of $P^-$ is the entire space $H$ -- because, by Theorem 13.24 (a) in [1],
$$\D(P^-)=\D_g:=\Big\{x\in H\colon \int_{\si(P)}g^2\,dE_{x,x}<\infty\Big\},$$
where $g(t):=1/t$. So, by Theorem 13.24 (b) in [1] with $g$ as above and $f(t):=t$, and in view of Definition 12.17 in [1] of a resolution of the identity,
$$PP^-=\Psi(f)\Psi(g)=\Psi(fg)=\Psi(1)=I_H,$$
where $I_H$ is the identity operator on $H$ and $\Psi(h):=\int_{\si(P)}h\,dE$. (Note the obvious typo in Theorem 13.24 (b) in [1], which has $\D_{fg}\in\D_g$ instead of $\D_{fg}\subseteq\D_g$.)

Thus, $P^-=P^{-1}$, as claimed.

[1] Functional Analysis: Rudin, Second Edition

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the assumption that $0$ is in the spectrum can be replaced by the much weaker assumption that $P$ is injective.

---

Assume that $P$ is a positive, self-adjoint injection with spectral decomposition
$$P= \int_0^\infty tdE(t).$$
Then injectivity of $P$ ensures that $E(\{0\})= 0$ so it makes sense to consider
$$A:=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}dE(t).$$
We claim that this operator is exactly $P^{-1}$ with its natural domain $\operatorname{Im}(P)= P(\mathscr{D}(P))$.
To see this, note first that if $\xi \in \mathscr{D}(P)$, then
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^2}dE_{P\xi, P\xi}(t) = \int_0^\infty dE_{\xi, \xi}= \|\xi\|^2 < \infty$$
where we used this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442445/identity-for-spectral-resolution-de-xi-xi-g2-de-eta-eta). It follows that the image of $P$ is contained in $\mathscr{D}(A)$. Moreover, by the multiplication theorem,
$$AP\subseteq \int_0^\infty dE = I$$
so that $AP\xi = \xi = P^{-1}P\xi$ for $\xi \in \mathscr{D}(P)$. We have proven that
$P^{-1}\subseteq A$. Since both operators are self-adjoint, we must have the equality $P^{-1}= A$.