# Identity for spectral resolution: $dE_{\xi, \xi}= |g|^2 dE_{\eta, \eta}$

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Let $E: \mathcal{F}\to B(H)$ be a regular resolution of the identity on the Hilbert space $H$, see e.g. Rudin's functional analysis book.

Suppose that $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is Borel-measurable and that $\xi \in \mathscr{D}\left(\int_\Omega g dE\right)=: \mathscr{D}_g$. We can then define
$$\eta:= \left(\int_\Omega  g dE\right)\xi\in H.$$
Is it true that
$$dE_{\eta, \eta}= |g|^2 dE_{\xi, \xi}?$$
I.e., if $A\in \mathcal{F}$, do we have
$$E_{\eta, \eta}(A)= \int_{A}|g|^2 dE_{\xi, \xi}.$$

I believe I can show this if $g$ is bounded. But I am mostly interested in the case where $g$ is unbounded.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I just posted an answer. I've never been too comfortable with unbounded operators, so maybe something is off. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g=\sum_k\beta_k\,1_{X_k}$ is simple,
$$
\Big\langle\Big(\int_\Omega g\,dE\Big)\xi,\xi\Big\rangle=\int_\Omega g\,dE_{\xi,\xi}=\sum_k\beta_k\,E_{\xi,\xi}(X_k)=\Big\langle\sum_k\beta_k\,E(X_k)\xi,\xi\Big\rangle. 
$$

Since $g$ is measurable, then there exist simple functions $g_n$ such that $g_n\to g$ and $|g_n|^2\nearrow |g|^2$ (this is easily achievable by finding first simple functions that increase to $(\operatorname{Re}g)^+$, $(\operatorname{Re}g)^-$, $(\operatorname{Im}g)^+$, $(\operatorname{Im}g)^-$, respectively).

For any $\nu$ we have, using monotone convergence in each of the sixteen integrals coming from decomposing $g$ and $dE_{\xi,\nu}$ as a linear combinations of positive functions/measures,

$$
\langle \eta,\nu\rangle=\int_\Omega g\,dE_{\xi,\nu}=\lim_n\int_\Omega g_n\,dE_{\xi,\nu}=\lim_n\Big\langle\Big(\int_\Omega g_n\,dE\Big)\xi,\nu\Big\rangle
$$

So, writing $g_n=\sum_k\beta_{n,k}\,1_{X_{n,k}}$,
\begin{align}
E_{\eta,\eta}(A)
&=\langle E(A)\eta,\eta\rangle
=\Big\langle E(A)\Big(\int_\Omega g\,dE\Big)\xi,\eta\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\Big\langle E(A)\Big(\int_\Omega g\,dE\Big)\xi,\Big(\int_\Omega g_n\,dE\Big)\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\sum_k\overline{\beta_{n,k}}\Big\langle E(A)\Big(\int_\Omega g\,dE\Big)\xi,E(X_{n,k})\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\sum_k\overline{\beta_{n,k}}\Big\langle \Big(\int_\Omega g\,dE\Big)\xi,E(A)E(X_{n,k})\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\sum_k\overline{\beta_{n,k}}\Big\langle \Big(\int_\Omega g\,dE\Big)\xi,E(A\cap X_{n,k})\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\lim_m\sum_k\sum_j\overline{\beta_{n,k}}\beta_{m,j}\Big\langle E(X_{m,j})\xi,E(A\cap X_{n,k})\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\lim_m\sum_k\sum_j\overline{\beta_{n,k}}\beta_{m,j}\Big\langle E(A\cap X_{n,k})E(X_{m,j})\xi,\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\lim_m\Big\langle \Big(\int_A \overline{g_n}g_m\,dE\Big)\xi,\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lim_n\Big\langle \Big(\int_A \overline{g_n}g\,dE\Big)\xi,\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\Big\langle \Big(\int_A \overline{g}g\,dE\Big)\xi,\xi\Big\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\int_A|g|^2\,dE_{\xi,\xi}.
\end{align}

Comment: This looks good. I will take a closer look to see if there are no hidden issues.

Comment: At some point, you write $g\ge 0$ is this a typo? Also, I think we can just use dominated convergence theorem to justify taking the limits outside (a little easier than monotone convergence on 16 integrals imo).

Comment: Yes, the $g\geq0$ was a typo. As for dominated convergence, not sure how you see it.

Comment: You take a sequence of simples with $|g_n|\nearrow |g|$. Then $|g|$ acts as the dominating function. Do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe it's me missing something. With what measure is $|g|$ supposed to be integrable?

Comment: With respect to the total variation $|E_{\xi, \eta}|$. The square integrability assumption on $g$ ensures the integrability with respect to this measure, which is why we can make sense of $\int g dE_{\xi,\eta}$.

Comment: Ok, I can see that the existence of $\int g\,dE_{\xi,nu}$ for every $\nu$ implies that $\int |g|\,d|E_{\xi,\nu}|<\infty$; and that's enough to use Dominated Convergence. But what "square integrability assumption?" (I have to admit that I didn't put much thought into what it means to be in the domain of $\int g\,dE$).

Comment: The domain of $\int g dE$ are precisely those $\xi$ such that $\int |g|^2 dE_{\xi,\xi}<\infty$. This is in Rudin's functional analysis book in the last chapter.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I never got to that chapter :D

Comment: Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure. You always ask interesting questions.